# Active power measurement via current probe, how does it work?

Tags: power, current-measurement, power-measurement

How does the [Emporia Vue 2](https://www.emporiaenergy.com/how-the-vue-energy-monitor-works) work?

It uses a current measurement: magnetic core with coil around it (that’s my understanding). However, without knowing voltage waveform, active power can't be calculated (only apparent power).

For example, if voltage were to be 90 degree out of phase with the current, then active power would be zero (all is reactive power). But the device does not know the voltage waveform; only current.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: 180 phase would be generating rather than receiving power. 90 out of phase is all reactive.

Comment: Only 1 voltage need to be known, guessing that others phases are the "same" values... if not, calculus should be a little more complicated.

Comment: Re, "...coil around electrical conductor..." FYI: The sense coil isn't wrapped around the conductor. It's wrapped around a magnetic core that the conductor passes through. Similar to [drawings shown here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/current-transformer.html) except that the Vue2 looks like it uses _split_ cores that can be snapped around the conductor instead of requiring the conductor to be disconnected, threaded through, and then re-connected.

Comment: Of course, 90 degrees, fixed my post. Thanks for clarifying on the coil. Answer was given by @RoyC; also measure the phase voltage which is the same everywhere (to first order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit is connected to the phase voltages so will be measuring those voltages. Current is measured by the current transformers on individual loads but the voltage on each of these loads will be the same allowing the meter to calculate power.

Comment: Oh I didn’t think of that! Right... instead of immediately rectifying, could do A/D to get voltage waveform. Voltage waveform to first order is the same every where (low voltage drops) while the different phase shifts are in the current